# Remove rows with leading missing values in a specific column by group with data.table

Tags: r, data.table, na, zoo

I have a data.table like this:

```
DT <- data.table(id = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 3)),
                 col1 = c(NA,1,2,NA,3,NA), col2 = c(NA,NA,5,NA,NA,NA))
   id col1 col2
1:  a   NA   NA
2:  a    1   NA
3:  a    2    5
4:  b   NA   NA
5:  b    3   NA
6:  b   NA   NA
```

For each id, I would like to remove rows with **leading** `NA`s in 'col1' using `zoo::na.trim`. Here's the result I'm expecting:

```
   id col1 col2
1:  a    1   NA
2:  a    2    5
3:  b    3   NA
4:  b   NA   NA
```

Here's what I have tried so far. This indeed removes leading `NA` in 'col1', but it omits 'col2' from the result:

```
DT[ , na.trim(col1), by = id]
   id V1
1:  a  1
2:  a  2
3:  b  3
```

This is also not working:

```
DT[ , .SD[na.trim(col1)], by = id]
   id col1 col2
1:  a   NA   NA
2:  a    1   NA
3:  b   NA   NA
```

Comment: Please specify the package that has `na.trim`

Comment: Sorry. It's `zoo`

Comment: There is a `sides` argument i..e. `DT[, zoo::na.trim(col1, sides = "left"), by = id]`

Comment: @akrun Yes, but this also removes col2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible solution without using the `zoo`-package:

```
DT[DT[, .I[!!cumsum(!is.na(col1))], by = id]$V1]
```

you get:

```
   id col1 col2
1:  a    1   NA
2:  a    2    5
3:  b    3   NA
4:  b   NA   NA
```

What this does:

- With `DT[, .I[!!cumsum(!is.na(col1))], id]$V1` you create a vector of rownumbers to keep. By using `!!cumsum(!is.na(col1))` you make sure that only the leading missing values of `col1` are omitted.
- Next you use that vector to subset the data.table.
- `!!cumsum(!is.na(col1))` does the same as `cumsum(!is.na(col1))!=0`. Using `!!` converts all number higher than zero to `TRUE` and all zeros to `FALSE`.
- `.I` isn't necessarily needed, you can also use: `DT[DT[, !!cumsum(!is.na(col1)), by = id]$V1]` which subsets the data.table with a logical vector.

---

Two alternatives with `cummax` by @lmo from the comments:

```
# alternative 1:
DT[DT[, !!(cummax(!is.na(col1))), by = id]$V1]

# alternative 2:
DT[as.logical(DT[, cummax(!is.na(col1)), by = id]$V1)]
```

Another alternative by @jogo:

```
DT[, .SD[!!cumsum(!is.na(col1))], by = id]
```

Another alternative by @Frank:

```
DT[, .SD[ rleid(col1) > 1L | !is.na(col1) ], by = id]
```

Comment: Can you explain the "!!" part? It's not in the data.table Reference manual

Comment: Also with `cummax` `DT[DT[, !!(cummax(!is.na(col1))), by=id]$V1])` or `DT[as.logical(DT[, cummax(!is.na(col1)), by=id]$V1)]`.

Comment: variant: `DT[, .SD[!!cumsum(!is.na(col1))], id]` or `DT[, .SD[as.logical(cumsum(!is.na(col1)))], id]`

Answer (score 4):

`na.trim` would be used like this with data.table.  See `?na.trim` for more info on its arguments.

```
DT[, na.trim(.SD, sides = "left", is.na = "all"), by = id]
```

giving:

```
   id col1 col2
1:  a    1   NA
2:  a    2    5
3:  b    3   NA
4:  b   NA   NA
```

ADDED:

In comment poster clarified that only column 1 NAs should be operated on by `na.trim`.  In that case append a column of row numbers, .I, and after involing `na.trim` subset using those row numbers.

```
DT[DT[, na.trim(data.table(col1, .I), "left"), by = id]$.I, ]
```

Comment: @GGrothendieck  I do not understand how this solution trims NAs only for `col1`. It doesn't seem to work with this example where there are no NAs in col2: `DT <- data.table(id=c(rep("a",5),rep("b",5)),col1=c(NA,1,NA,2,NA,NA,3,4,NA,5),col2=1:10)`

Comment: Didn't understand that.  I have now added code at the end to only apply na.trim to col1 and then take the rows that are left.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `1:.N >= which.max(...)` to subset the required rows

```
> DT[, .SD[1:.N >= which.max(!is.na(col1))], id]
   id col1 col2
1:  a    1   NA
2:  a    2    5
3:  b    3   NA
4:  b   NA   NA
```